# How does this glob.glob order the files

Tags: python, glob

I have files labelled from 1 to 1024 all with .png at the end.

How does this line of code order the files:

```
File = glob.glob('./test/art/*.png')
File.sort(key = lambda f: int(filter(str.isdigit, f)))
```

Comment: What order do you see when you run it?

Comment: I'm working on github through googe colab. Im not sure  how to actually see the files im working with

Comment: Sort in python sorts in ascending order by default looking at the statement it will sort those where the key is a digit in ascending order

Comment: You can always `print()` to see what Filenames you are working with.